# Django lib to create xls-files over 65k rows?

Tags: django, excel, xlwt

Is there an excel-lib for Django, whom doesn’t put a limit at 65k+ rows?

Or plan B: dirty workaround to make xlwt produce the desired files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the new Excel format, xlsx, instead of the old one with xls extension. After Excel 2007 the 65.000 row limit was increased to 1 million rows. Unfortunately, I don't know about Django and I can't suggest any library to produce the new Excel format.

Comment: Ah, missing basic excel-knowledge. :|